# Blocking frame switch with Java

Tags: java, jframe

I would like to block the frame switch request of the user in my java Application; Example:

I have the main frame with full size and the setup frame with a smaller size (400,400 for example). While the setup frame is opened I wouldnt like to let the user to acess the Main Frame, he can do this only if he closes the setup frame.

That might one duplicated question and I'm sorry for that, but I couldnt find the specific term to research what I want, I was try something like "Window focus on java" but I think I was researching in the wrong direction..

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: The term you are looking for is modal (like modal dialogs), you may be able to do this by extending a modal JDialog.

Comment: Invariably when I help people on issues like this, the real solution ends up being "seriously, don't use more than one `JFrame`."  If you _really_ need a popup, use a dialog; otherwise use a `JLayeredPane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use a modal dialog. If this is not an option, you will have to create a handler yourself that fires whenever a frame gets focus and checks if it is the right frame. If not, the handler must focus on the important frame.

Comment: There are no modal JFrame's, JDialog exists for this purpose.

Comment: ty guys, now I can move forward

Comment: The code is working, but whats the deal with that flash that normally we see in other apps? Is there a way to enable this or this is a manual treatment?

Comment: This is automatic - I found on my code I was using SETUP_DIALOG.setFocusableWindowState(false); and this was removing the default pattern of the Dialog

Answer (score 0):

set child jframe or whatever swing component as modal window